# What is the best way to sync podcasts between two computers' iTunes accounts?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

What is the best way to sync podcasts between two computers' iTunes accounts?

Comment: Do you mean the podcasts themselves (the files) or also the meta info (playback position, etc.)?